# open and resize an image from a folder on the server in PHP and save it back

Tags: php

Is there anyway select an image from a folder inside the server, instead of submitting from HTML on a client side, and work on it using PHP?
Then I want to resize the image and save as a different name to the same folder on the server. This gonna be by clicking a button from client side.

Comment: I would call that FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/image) [class](https://github.com/kohana/image).

```
// get image for manipulate from temp folder
$image = new Image($sourcePath);
// manipulate
$image->resize($targetWidth, $targetHeight, Image::AUTO)->sharpen(1)->quality(95)->save($resultPath);
```

Comment: I have code ready for image resizing and other things. The problem is it is work when I grab the file from desktop, but not working when grab from server. location of file on the server:  $pic = "../user/$log_email/$avatar";

 $fileName = $_FILES["$pic"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["$pic"]["tmp_name"];
 $fileType = $_FILES["$pic"]["type"];
 $fileSize = $_FILES["$pic"]["size"];
 $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["$pic"]["error"];